# The SSL certificate doesn't established

Tags: ssl, iis-7.5, certificate

situation following:
Windows Server 2008 R2 platform.
Certificate installation in the IIS Manager occurs successfully with *.cer  file but if I refresh the manager (F5), the certificate vanishes from the list. And, respectively in the Bindings window, at https addition, the certificate is absent in the menu. Thus if to open certificates via the MMS console, it can be seen in the Personal store. Whether there is any possibility to make so that the web server could "see" this certificate or how to make so that it didn't disappear from the list?
Prompt how to solve this problem, thanks in advance!

P.S. The certificate is acquired in tawte. In total that to me provided, these are account data where it is possible simply with save-pastit the certificate in 2 options: PKCS#7 and X.509. [Here](https://search.thawte.com/support/ssl-digital-certificates/index?page=content&id=SO10664) is the manual I used.
P.S.2 If Complete Certificate Request with *.p7b I get an error:

> Cannot find the certificate request that is associated with this certificate file. Acertificate request must be comleted on the computer where the request was created.

Comment: To apply for a certificate you must first generate a key-pair - did you do that? Another way to get at the same thing -> where is the CSR you provided the CA (Thawte?) when you enrolled for the certificate?

Answer (score 0):

Is this actually the server you created the certificate request on?

Look [here](http://www.digicert.com/ssl-certificate-installation-microsoft-iis-7.htm) under point 7 they have some additional tips on this specific situation

Its also possible you have a problem with the friendly name of the certificate perhaps [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/959216) helps?

Answer (score 0):

If the certificate is missing its private key, it will be useless to IIS; looks like this is your case.

In order to fix this, you can use the steps described here:

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/889651/en-us